# JavaScript not loading on Heroku but works locally

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm making an app on Rails, and it works locally, but images and JavaScript is not loading when I try to deploy it on Heroku.

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I renamed all other javascripts alphabetically so that require_tree will list it the way i want it. The order of which it loads works locally.

Below is the application.rb:

```
OlgasHelpers::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

Please Help! If you need any more files I will post, thanks!

EDIT:
Here's my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.2'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'devise'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'pg'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'simple_form', '>= 3.0.0.rc'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'rails_12factor'
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_19, :mri_20, :rbx]
  gem 'hub', :require=>nil
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner', '1.0.1'
  gem 'email_spec'
end
```

Comment: What version of rails, 3 or 4?

Comment: Did you install the 12factor gem?

Comment: Yes, I just put up my gemfile.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: No, I used dev tool on chrome and that's not showing me any errors. Also i went to network tab and it loads the javascript file... I really have no clue what's creating the errors.

Comment: Oh, you said in your question 'javascript is not loading', but you just said it loaded.  So what's actually happening?  What are the errors?

Comment: Sorry, it's loading, but it's not running. Here's the app http://boiling-sea-1027.herokuapp.com/#home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript is loading fine.  You have an error because you're using an older plugin which tries to use $.browser which has now been removed from jQuery (see note here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/).

You need to install the jQuery.migrate plugin: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been stuck on this for days!